# Passing EditText to a Toast

Tags: android, toast

I'm trying to write a simple program that will take the contents of one editText and pass it to a Toast after a button is clicked. Initially, this was a tutorial that simply displayed a Toast when the button is clicked, but I want to pass a value from the EditText to the 'text' parameter of Toast. I'm not getting any errors in Eclipse, but the emulator stops unexpectedly.

Here is my java code:

```
package event.handling;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HandlerExamples extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.testButton);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        Toast toast = Toast (text);
        toast.show();       
    }
private Toast Toast(EditText text) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
}
```

Eventually I am going to use four different EditText views and simply add the numbers entered together and display the answer in a Toast.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 5):

You return null from the `Toast`  method and then call this null object, so you get a `NullPointerException`.

It should be something like this:

```
private Toast Toast(EditText text) {
    return Toast.makeText(this, text.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
}
```

BTW, this is a bad naming, I would recommend `private Toast toastFromEditText(EditText text)` or similar.

Comment: That solved it...now I am on to adding multiple EditText views! More learning ahead! Thanks so much!